# What is the model structure on simiplicial $B$-modules?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-functors, higher-category-theory

In the following [notes Lemma 4.12](https://www.math.hu-berlin.de/%7Ebrunsgre/notes/2013-deformation_theory.pdf)

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. $sAlg_A$ the category of simplicial$A$-algebras. Let $B\in sAlg_A$, then we can consider the category of $B$-module objects in  the category of simplicial $A$-modules. This is denoted $Mod^s_B$ in the paper.

What is the right way to define the model structure on $Mod^s_B$. It is not specified in the paper.

Comment: I would guess it’s any one that has as its weak equivalences the morphisms that are weak homotopy equivalences of simplicial sets. For general reasons there will be one where the fibrations are Kan fibrations, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Note that you don't need $A$ in the definition of $Mod^s_B$. There will be a model structure where fibrations and weak equivalences are the ones given in $\mathbf{sSet}$. You could check out *Algebras and modules in monoidal model categories* by Schwede and Shipley - the case you're interested in is the example "Simplicial abelian groups"

Comment: Can you use the Dold Kan correspondance for this somehow? Just a thought.